# Levels page Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Im trying to implement a levels style page into my app. Im doing an advent calendar style app where there is a calendar page (similar to a level selection page), where the user selects a day and it redirects you to a page displaying a xmas message.

Ive gotten a similar page working using the example I found here;
http://www.christianpeeters.com/corona-sdk/level-selection-template-for-corona-sdk/

However when I implemented this in my app, when I select the day/level available to open, once it is completed the image does not transition to the completed image (a green check), and the day/level next to it is still locked when it should be available.

My code can be found below, and help would be great. Thanks!

**Main**

```
require "CiderDebugger";
-- Add a global background
local background = display.newImage("xmasbg.jpg",160, 240,300,480)

local function removeFlake(target)
        target:removeSelf()
        target = nil
end

local function spawnSnowFlake()
        local flake = display.newImage("snowflake.png")
        --group:insert(flake)
        flake.x = math.random(display.contentWidth)
        flake.y = -2
        local wind = math.random(80) - 40
        transition.to(flake,{time=math.random(3000) + 3000, y = display.contentHeight + 2, x = flake.x + wind, onComplete=removeFlake})
        --group:insert(flake)
end

local function makeSnow(event)
      if math.random(10) == 1 then -- adjust speed here by making the random number higher or lower
            spawnSnowFlake()
      end
      return true
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",makeSnow)

-- Initialize our global variables
--local globals = require( "globals" )

-- main.lua
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
storyboard.purgeOnScreenChange = true
storyboard.gotoScene( "menu_scene" )
```

**menu_scene**

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )

local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local hohoho = audio.loadSound("xmas.wav")

-- Clear previous scene
storyboard.removeAll()

-- local forward references should go here --
local function buttonHit(event)
    audio.play(hohoho)
    storyboard.gotoScene(event.target.goto, {effect = "slideRight"})

end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
  local group = self.view

--local background = display.newImage("xmasbg.jpg",160, 240,300,480)
--group:insert(background)
local hohoho = audio.loadSound("xmas.wav")
--group:insert(hohoho)
local bgMusic = audio.loadSound("bgmusic.wav")
--group:insert(bgMusic)
local calendarButton = display.newImage("calendarButton.png", 160, 170)
group:insert(calendarButton)
calendarButton:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
calendarButton.goto = "calendar_scene"

local creditsButton = display.newImage("creditsButton.png", 160, 250)
group:insert(creditsButton)
creditsButton:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
creditsButton.goto = "credits_scene"

local sound = display.newImage("speaker117.png", 290, 495)
group:insert(sound)

local backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( bgMusic, { channel=1, loops=-1, fadein=5000 } )

--Until Xmas Text
local xmasText = display.newText("Until Christmas", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 30)
xmasText: setTextColor( 0, 0,.75)
xmasText.x, xmasText.y = 160, 80
group:insert(xmasText)


--The number of days remaining
local dayText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 30 )
dayText:setTextColor( 0, 0, .75)
dayText.x, dayText.y = 55, 45
group:insert(dayText)

--The number of hours remaining
local hourText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 30 )
hourText:setTextColor( 0, 0, .75)
hourText.x, hourText.y = 160, 45
group:insert(hourText)

--The number of minutes remaining
local minutesText = display.newText( "", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 30 )
minutesText:setTextColor( 0, 0, .75)
minutesText.x, minutesText.y = 255, 45
group:insert(minutesText)

-- Create labels to indicate what the numbers mean
local dayLabel = display.newText( "Days", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 30 )
dayLabel:setTextColor( 0, 0, .75 )
dayLabel.x = 60; dayLabel.y = 5
group:insert(dayLabel)

local hourLabel = display.newText( "Hours", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 30)
hourLabel:setTextColor( 0, 0, .75 )
hourLabel.x = 160; hourLabel.y = 5
group:insert(hourLabel)

local minuteLabel = display.newText( "Mins", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 30 )
minuteLabel:setTextColor( 0, 0, .75 )
minuteLabel.x = 260; minuteLabel.y = 5
group:insert(minuteLabel)

--Function to update the countdown clock
local function updateTime()
local time = os.date("*t")

local daysLeft = 358 - time.yday
if (daysLeft < 10) then
daysLeft = "0" .. daysLeft
end
dayText.text = daysLeft

local hoursLeft = 23 - time.hour
if (hoursLeft < 10) then
hoursLeft = "0" .. hoursLeft
end
hourText.text = hoursLeft

local minutesLeft = 60 - time.min
if (minutesLeft < 10) then
minutesLeft = "0" .. minutesLeft
end
minutesText.text = minutesLeft


end

--Update the time once immediately to display the correct time
updateTime()

-- Update the clock once per second
local clockTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, updateTime, -1 )

--[[function calendarButton:tap(event)
    audio.play(hohoho)
    calendarButton:removeSelf()
    display.newImage("pushedCalendarButton.png", 160, 170)
end--]]

--[[function creditsButton:tap(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene("credits_scene")
    audio.play(hohoho)
    creditsButton:removeSelf()
    --display.newImage("pushedCreditsButton.png", 160, 250)
end]]--

function sound: tap(event)
    --[[if(self.status == "playing") then
        sound:removeSelf()
        display.newImage("mute.png", 290, 495)
        audio.pause()
        self.status = "paused"

    elseif(self.status == "paused") then
        display.newImage("speaker117.png", 290, 495)
        audio.play()
        --self.status = "paused"



    end--]]


    sound:removeSelf()
    display.newImage("mute.png", 290, 495)
    audio.stop()
end



--[[local function removeFlake(target)
        target:removeSelf()
        target = nil
end

local function spawnSnowFlake()
        local flake = display.newImage("snowflake.png")
        --group:insert(flake)
        flake.x = math.random(display.contentWidth)
        flake.y = -2
        local wind = math.random(80) - 40
        transition.to(flake,{time=math.random(3000) + 3000, y = display.contentHeight + 2, x = flake.x + wind, onComplete=removeFlake})
        --group:insert(flake)
end

local function makeSnow(event)
      if math.random(10) == 1 then -- adjust speed here by making the random number higher or lower
            spawnSnowFlake()
      end
      return true
end



Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",makeSnow)--]]
calendarButton:addEventListener("tap", calendarButton)
--creditsButton:addEventListener("tap", creditsButton)
sound:addEventListener("tap", sound)

end


-- Called BEFORE scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:willEnterScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called AFTER scene has finished moving offscreen:
function scene:didExitScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display view)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called if/when overlay scene is displayed via storyboard.showOverlay()
function scene:overlayBegan( event )
  local group = self.view
  local overlay_name = event.sceneName  -- name of the overlay scene

end


-- Called if/when overlay scene is hidden/removed via storyboard.hideOverlay()
function scene:overlayEnded( event )
  local group = self.view
  local overlay_name = event.sceneName  -- name of the overlay scene

end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "willEnterScene" event is dispatched before scene transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "willEnterScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "didExitScene" event is dispatched after scene has finished transitioning out
scene:addEventListener( "didExitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-- "overlayBegan" event is dispatched when an overlay scene is shown
scene:addEventListener( "overlayBegan", scene )

-- "overlayEnded" event is dispatched when an overlay scene is hidden/removed
scene:addEventListener( "overlayEnded", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

**calendar_scene**

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local hohoho = audio.loadSound("xmas.wav")

-- Clear previous scene
storyboard.removeAll()

-- local forward references should go here --

levels = 
{   
1, 2, 2, 2 ,2,  --1 means level is open to  be played (level.png)
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  --2 means level is locked (locked.png)
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  --3 means level is completed (greenchecked.png)
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
}

images ={
    { getFile = "gift.png", types = "play"},
    { getFile = "lock.png", types = "locked"},
    { getFile = "greenchecked.png", types = "done"}
}

local function buttonHit(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene ( event.target.destination, {effect = "slideLeft"} )
        audio.play(hohoho)
    print( event.target.destination)
        return true
end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
  local group = self.view

    local levelIndex = 0
            for i=0,4 do
               for j=1,5 do

                    tablePlace =   i*5 + j  
                    levelIndex = levelIndex + 1
                    local imagesId = levels[levelIndex] 
                    levelImg = display.newImageRect (images[imagesId].getFile , 50, 50 )
                    levelImg.x = -22 + (j*62)
                    levelImg.y  = 130+ (i*70)
                    levelImg.anchorY = .8
                    group:insert(levelImg)

                    local levelText = display.newText(tablePlace,0,0,native.systemFont,28)
                    levelText.x = -22 + (j*62)
                    levelText.y = 125+ (i*70)
                    group:insert(levelText)

                    levelImg.destination = "level0"..tostring(tablePlace)

                    if images[imagesId].types ~= "locked" then
                    levelImg:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
                    end
                end
            end

    local heading = display.newText("Christmas Countdown", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 31)
        heading: setTextColor( .75, 0, 0)
        heading.x, heading.y = 160, 35
        group:insert(heading)

        local backButton = display.newImage("backButton.png", 43, 495)
        group:insert(backButton)
        backButton:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
        backButton.destination = "menu_scene"
end


-- Called BEFORE scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:willEnterScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called AFTER scene has finished moving offscreen:
function scene:didExitScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display view)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called if/when overlay scene is displayed via storyboard.showOverlay()
function scene:overlayBegan( event )
  local group = self.view
  local overlay_name = event.sceneName  -- name of the overlay scene

end


-- Called if/when overlay scene is hidden/removed via storyboard.hideOverlay()
function scene:overlayEnded( event )
  local group = self.view
  local overlay_name = event.sceneName  -- name of the overlay scene

end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "willEnterScene" event is dispatched before scene transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "willEnterScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "didExitScene" event is dispatched after scene has finished transitioning out
scene:addEventListener( "didExitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-- "overlayBegan" event is dispatched when an overlay scene is shown
scene:addEventListener( "overlayBegan", scene )

-- "overlayEnded" event is dispatched when an overlay scene is hidden/removed
scene:addEventListener( "overlayEnded", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

**level01**

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local widget = require ("widget")
local calendar_scenefile = require ("calendar_scene")


-- local forward references should go here --

local completegameBtn


local function buttonHit(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene (  event.target.destination, {effect = "slideLeft"} )
    return true
end


-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    local title = display.newText( "Level 1", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 38 )
    title.x = 160
    title.y = display.screenOriginY + 40
    group:insert(title)

    local backBtn = display.newText(  "Back", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 25 )
    backBtn.x = display.screenOriginX + 50
    backBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 30 
    backBtn.destination = "calendar_scene" 
    backBtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
    group:insert(backBtn)
end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

        local function btnClicked (event)
    --levelProgress = levelProgress + 1
    levels[1] = 3
    levels[2] = 1
    completegameBtn.destination = "calendar_scene" 
    completegameBtn:addEventListener("tap", buttonHit)
    end

    completegameBtn = widget.newButton { label = "Complete game", onRelease=btnClicked}
    completegameBtn.x = 160
    completegameBtn.y = 240
    group:insert (completegameBtn)
end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)
    -- Remove listeners attached to the Runtime, timers, transitions, audio tracks

end

-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. remove listeners, widgets, save state, etc.)
    -- Remove listeners attached to the Runtime, timers, transitions, audio tracks

end



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: Your indentation is all messed up, making it difficult to see the structure of the code. Please pay attention to formatting on SO: replace all tabs by spaces and make sure code is aligned as it should be.

Comment: Sorry Im very knew to SO (and programming itself!). I'll try edit it to a more readable format. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @kanedk90 Are you going to calendar_scene from main.lua? If so, please include main.lua in your post...

Comment: @Melquiades Im going from my menu_scene to the calendar scene. I just added the menu_scene and main to files above.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the calls to `removeAll`, it is unlikely you need them: purging and removing (unloading) scenes is primarily for saving memory, so the purge and removal functions should only be used for scenes that are rarely re-visited but contain lots of objects. For all other scenes (those visited often, or that don't have lots of objects), they are not necessary, and can lead to subtle bugs as you may be experiencing.

Note that `storyboard.purgeOnScreenChange` does not exist, you probably intended `storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange`. But the typo means the setting stayed false, so it is not part of the issue you are experiencing. But if you fix the typo, also comment out that line too in `main.lua` otherwise it will have same effect.

So comment out any lines that have to do with the storyboard scene purge and removal functions, and if you feel you really need them (because the default Corona behavior is inadequate), then re-introduce in one place and test going between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Corona has moved to **Composer** to manage scenes, instead of **Storyboard**. That being said, your levels are still locked because the code that draws your levels and sets listeners is in **createScene** function, which in turn is called only once in your case, as Corona won't call **createScene** if your scene has not been completely destroyed.

From the docs for scene:create() in Composer (applies to Storyboard as well):

> Note that the scene:create() function is only called if the scene’s
>   view does not exist — that is, it will be called the first time the
>   scene is loaded. However, Composer tries to keep the scene in memory
>   assuming that you’ll revisit it later, so if the scene remains in
>   memory, scene:create() will not be called.

So even though you're modifying global levels table, when you're back in **calendar_scene**, createScene is NOT being called again. You have 3 choices:

1. You could move your drawing/setting listeners code to **willEnterScene**
   function, which will be called again when you're back in
   calendar_scene, this time with updated values (but it's not a good idea - remember to remove display objects in exitScene, null listeners etc...)
2. Use storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange (and not purgeOnScreenChange, as
   Schollii noticed) and set it to true, this way the scene will be
   destroyed when you leave it, meaning that createScene will be called
   again when you're back from level selection (better, but again, it's more important to understand scene memory management and code accordingly, than to use short cuts, although sometimes these have valid uses too).
3. [Migrate](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/composer/migration.html) your code to Composer API, and at the same time, it might be
   a good idea to [understand scene management](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/). Then draw your level selection, and update as necessary when back from particular level.